# React not rendering Route Components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-component

I am building a consumer facing app with a admin dashboard. I want to keep the routing separate for them and so trying to delegate :-

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

//styles
import './style/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss';

//apps
import Mainapp from './mainapp/Mainapp';
import Admin from './admin/Admin';

const MainappContainer = () => (
  <Mainapp />
);

const AdminContainer = () => (
  <Admin />
);

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/admin" component={AdminContainer}/>
            <Route path="/" component={MainappContainer}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Admin.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


//styles
import './admin-style.scss';

//layout
import ControlPanel from './component/layout/ControlPanel';
import Navbar from './component/layout/Navbar';

//pages
import Quote from './component/pages/quote/Quote';

class Admin extends Component{
    render(){
      return (
        <div className="adminWrapper">
          <ControlPanel />
          <section className="viewPanel">
            <Navbar />
            <Router>
              <Route path="/quote" component={Quote}/>
            </Router>
          </section>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  export default Admin;
```

However when I hit the URL

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/quote
```

it doesn't seem to load the quote component

Quote.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Quote extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="float-right pr-3">
                <h3>
                    Quote Page
                </h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Quote;
```

Comment: The path for the quote page isn't /admin/quote if you're already in /admin.

Comment: tried "/quote", still gives a blank page

Comment: The other problem is that your parent there is exact, so only matches the root /admin

Comment: Remove exact from this **<Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminContainer}/>**

Comment: And change **<Route exact path="/admin/quote" component={Quote}/>** to **<Route exact path="/quote" component={Quote}/>**

Comment: updated question by removing exact and correcting path

Comment: are you sure you need an extra `Router` in Admin.js?

Comment: and it must be `<Route path="/admin/quote" component={Quote}/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [Nested Routing Example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/example-nested-routing)

The main changes you need to do are:
1. Remove the `<Router></Router>` from `Admin` component and
2. Prepend `match.path` to `"/quotes"`, like it is done in `Topics` component in the example. In the example, `Topics` is a function component so it is receiving `match` as function parameter. As your `Admin` component is class component, you can access it as `this.props.match` in `render` method.

```
<Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/quote`} component={Quote}/>
```

Comment: Yes I did this but I keep getting this error - 'Cannot read property 'path' of undefined'. I am using ES6.

Comment: That's because your component for `/admin` path is `AdminContainer`, which is not passing the down the received props to `Admin`. Change it to `const AdminContainer = (props) => ( <Admin {...props} /> );`

Comment: I tried this - but i keep getting redirected to a page which is the equivalent of localhost/quote. where i want to display my version of quote inside a div tag on another page

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with nested subroutes, the easiest solution is to use [match](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match).

> path - (string) The path pattern used to match. Useful for building nested 
>   Routes.
>
> url - (string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful for building
>   nested Links.

By design, components placed inside a Route's `component` render method are given several additional props from react-router-dom. Among them are [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) and `match`. You can leverage these props to either to match against sub routes and/or to control browser history location.

In addition, you only need **one** instance of `BrowserRouter` sitting at the top-level of the application, then you can use `Switch` to optionally render any main or sub routes. And you don't need to use class components unless you're utilizing `state` and/or a class field.

**A very basic, rudimentary working example of your application**:

[image: Edit React-Router-Dom Nested Routing]

---

**src/components/Admin/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ControlPanel from "../ControlPanel";
import Quote from "../Quote";

// since Admin is placed inside a Route's component render
// method, it has access to history and match
function Admin({ history, match }) {
  return (
    <div className="adminWrapper">
      <ControlPanel />
      <section className="viewPanel">
        <Link to={`${match.url}/quote`}>View quote</Link>
        <br />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={`${match.path}/quote`} component={Quote} />
        </Switch>
      </section>
      <br />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => history.goBack()}>
        Go Back
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Admin;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Admin from "./components/Admin";

const linkStyle = {
  padding: "0 10px"
};

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Link style={linkStyle} to="/">
        Home
      </Link>
      <Link style={linkStyle} to="/admin">
        Admin
      </Link>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        <Route path="/" render={() => <h1>Main App</h1>} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: i think this is where he is doing wrong. ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root")); i thing you won the bounty. congrats

Comment: How can i use match on a class component? Where this function has history and match as arguments - I can't find a place to incorporate match in a class component to be able to try to follow this example

Comment: @Mel - Before moving forward, I'd highly recommend stepping back and investing in some learning and education. I think you're trying to do too much and too fast. Please consider investing in this online, at your own pace, course: https://www.udemy.com/course/react-2nd-edition/. As of writing, it's only $10 and it covers a lot of fundamentals, its as slow or as fast past as you need, and it comes with in-depth explanations. I enrolled and completed it when I was first learning, and I found it to be an invaluable tool.

Comment: That said, to answer your question... class based components have `this.props`. If a class component is passed into a Route's `component` property, it'll be merged with Route props: `this.props.history`, `this.props.match`, and `this.props.location`.

Comment: I've done both udemy react classes. I find the explanations skim over what is actually happening, but I'll do it again in case I am better able to substantively understand what the steps are explaining. The thing is, I tried this.props.match - and got redirected to localhost/account immediately (instead of on a refresh). That is not what I'm looking to achieve. Ill redo the udemy and try to find a way to get this to render inside the dash. Thank you very much for trying to help.

Comment: If you're trying to authenticate across refreshes/different browser sessions, then you'll need to persist something: A token in local storage, a browser cookie... something secure. Then this needs to be authenticated (by sending a request to your server to verify the token/cookie) before the entire application is loaded. For example, using Context/Redux, you can set an initial `isLoading:true` property. This property prevents the entire app from loading until the server authenticates the request, and then its response will set the `isLoading` prop is set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminContainer}/>     
 <Route exact path="/admin/quote" component={Quote}/>
```

This won't route you to /admin/quote instead it will route you to /admin/admin/quote.

Since it is inside admin just /quote is enough

```
<Route path="/admin" component={AdminContainer}/>
<Route path="/quote" component={Quote}/>
```

Comment: try copy pasting once

Comment: removing exact makes the page remain on dashboard, however the quote route is still not loading